# How to copy files incrementally from FTP server to Hadoop HDFS

Tags: hadoop, ftp, hdfs

We have an FTP server, every day lot of files get uploaded to the FTP server, I need to copy all these files in HDFS.

Every time it should only download incremental files i.e. if first time it has downloaded 10 files and after that FTP have uploaded 5 new files; in the next iteration of job it should only download new 5 files in HDFS.

We are not using Nifi or Kafka connect.

Do we have any good solution around this to accomplish this task.

Comment: Do you use shell scripts in your environment?

Comment: @roh No, but if using shell is elegant solution , please discuss

Comment: @nilesh1212..would you like to share the details for the solution you have implemented..I am too stuck with same problem..I dont want to ftp my files to local due to space issues

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the touch file in the LFTP job, below is my explanation and code for that. Check out the comments at every step.

```
#!bin/bash
#SomeConfigs
TOUCHFILE='/somepath/inYourLocal/someFilename.touch'
RemoteSFTPserverPath='/Remote/Server/path/toTheFiles'
LocalPath='/Local/Path/toReceiveTheFiles'
FTP_Server_UserName='someUser'
FTP_Server_Password='SomePassword'
ServerIP='//127.12.11.35'

#Transfer files from FTP Server #This is the main command
ftp_command="lftp -e 'mirror --only-missing --newer-than=${TOUCHFILE} --older-than=now-2minutes --parallel=4 --no-recursion --include "SomeFileName*.csv"  ${RemoteSFTPserverPath}/ ${LocalPath}/;exit' -u ${FTP_Server_UserName},${FTP_Server_Password} sftp:${ServerIP}"

#CommandToexecute The Job
eval ${ftp_command}

#After finishing the lftp job You have to update the touch file for the next job
#This will update to current timestamp
touch /somepath/inYourLocal/someFilename.touch

#If you want to update with the last file received time
TchDate=$(stat -c %y "$(ls -1t ${LocalPath} | head -n1)" | date)
touch -d ${TchDate} /somepath/inYourLocal/someFilename.touch

#Stat on latest file in remote server #You can do this way also
TchDate=$(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${FTP_Server_UserName}@${FTP_Server_Password} "stat -c %y \"$(ls -1t ${RemoteSFTPserverPath}/ | head -n1)\" | date")
touch -d ${TchDate} /somepath/inYourLocal/someFilename.touch

#Once you have the files in your local you can copy them to hdfs

hdfs dfs -put -f /Local/Path/toReceiveTheFiles/*.csv /HDFS/PATH

#Remove the files in local so that you can accommodate for the upcoming files
rm -r -f /Local/Path/toReceiveTheFiles/*.csv
```

In the LFTP job, you have lot of options `man lftp` will be your best source

Comment: @nilesh1212 let me know if you stuck somewhere, there might be some typos as I quickly wrote the above code, watch out for that.